# Is it preferred to return data as plain text on Ecommerce websites - AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a big concern on a E-commerce website.

> My question is that is it safe or preferred approach to `pass plain ajax response` especially where calculations and quantity is updated?

For example..

When i am loading the product page then Price and other details like product qty, weight, diamonds are getting populated by ajax call.

on page load query is

**product.php**

```
$sql = select * from prdrd where id=$id
$r = mysqli_query($sql,$con);
while(){
   $row[] = $data;
   echo json_encode($row);
}
```

**Product.php page is called via Ajax**

then in jQuery i am updating main product page as

```
$("#proce").html(/*val retrnd by ajax*/);
.. so on
```

and same approach when somebody changes quantity in cart then updated price can be seen as a response plain text as json **updprc:25541**.

All things are working perfect but i feel big security concern here..

> Also i tried storing values in session and that is a good idea but then i did not find anyway to update page after ajax call through session variables.

Sorry for long post but i really want to get proper idea of secure implementation without https://

Comment: without https, you are at risk no matter what

Comment: but atleast is there anyway to handle plain ajax requests please

Comment: well no it they are submitted un protected there is nothing to stop interception\minipulation